# Auto populated in form with XML

Tags: c#, xml, forms, winforms

I have a simple form that has

- 5 checkboxes (checkBox1..5)
- one Savebtn
- one Loadbtn

```
writer.WriteStartElement("Item");
writer.WriteAttributeString("Item1", checkBox1.Checked ? "Bought1" : "No1");

writer.WriteAttributeString("Item2", checkBox2.Checked ? "Bought2" : "No2");

writer.WriteAttributeString("Item3", checkBox3.Checked ? "Bought3" : "No3");

writer.WriteAttributeString("Item4", checkBox4.Checked ? "Bought4" : "No4");

writer.WriteAttributeString("Item5", checkBox5.Checked ? "Bought5" : "No5");
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

I save user selections in a xml file (Savebtn)

I am now stuck loading this file.
I expect as I click the Loadbtn and get the xml file address, automatically based on the tag values populated in form.

ex:

```
<Item Item1="Bought1" Item2="No2" Item3="No3" Item4="No4" Item5="Bought5" />
```

in form should be chkBox1 (checked), chkBox5 (checked)
please help me.

Comment: You could use Bindings, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-5.0
Create a class with the necessary properties then just save/load the info from/into the class, the bindings will do the rest for you

Comment: yes, but I should use Xml format

Comment: How is your question is related to WPF? CheckBox.Checked property do have Windows.Forms.CheckBox controls, not the WPF ones. Do you have both [Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window?view=net-5.0) and [Form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form?view=net-5.0) objects in your project? How did you try to read back the xml file?

Comment: You can use the format that you want to save/load, either being xml or json, it doesn't matter for what I have told. you just need to use the Serialize/deserialize for the format that you use. If this is WinForms, WinForms suports also bindings

Answer (score 0):

I think your best solution is to create a dedicated class for the data you wish to save, then store it in XML using `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`.

Then you can feed your class to the `Serialize` function with a `System.IO.FileStream` and get it back with `Deserialize`.

That way, when you load from the file, you load a whole object that's ready for anything.

```
public class MyData
{
    public bool mycheck;

    public MyData() { mycheck = false; }

    string savepath = "C:\\mydata.xml";
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer dataSerializer;

    public void Save()
    {
        if(dataSerializer == null)
        {
            dataSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData));
        }
        using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(savepath, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
        {
            dataSerializer.Serialize(fs, this);
        }
    }

    public MyData Load()
    {
        if(dataSerializer == null)
        {
            dataSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData));
        }
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(savepath))
        {
            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(savepath, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
            {
                MyData md = null;
                try
                {
                    md = dataSerializer.Deserialize(fs) as MyData;
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
                return md;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return new MyData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Serialize and deserialize an UIElement? I don't think it is a good idea... Anyways, CheckBox.Checked is WinForms, don't know why the question is tagged with wpf.

Comment: @Steeeve You are totally right. LOL. Besides, that's not what I do anyway. I edited it to something more sane.